# How to test real Windows Store 8.1 in-app purchases with CurrentApp?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase, windows-8.1-universal

I have an universal windows app (Windows Store 8.1 & Windows Phone 8.1, NOT UWP!), published it (both Win and WP packages) as hidden (*Hide this app in the Store. Customers with a direct link to the app’s listing can still download it, except on Windows 8 and Windows 8.1*) but it looks like that people can access app from Windows Phone 8.1, Windows 10, but not from Windows 8.1.

Indeed, on Windows Phone 8.1 (even on simulator) I can debug "real" in-app purchases using CurrentApp instead of CurrentAppSimulator, and even can download app using direct link.
But when I try to use in-app in Windows Store version it doesn't work: Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync() throws Exception HRESULT: 0x801900CC ("no content"). 
I've read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963888) but in my case all the packages are published, so Store knows about my in-app products!

In case with WP8.1 I had to add:

```
 <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="my old-style app id" PhonePublisherId="my publisher id" />
```

into the app manifest.

Maybe there is something similar for Win Store 8.1 apps? Is there a way to test real in-apps on Windows 8.1 before making app available for all?

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to use in-app in Windows Store version it doesn't work: Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync() throws Exception HRESULT: 0x801900CC ("no content").

About your first problem, we can see that the Store server is not aware of your app having the In-app purchase that you purchase. As your description, you confirm that your app has been submitted in the store and got it approved, but can you check the In-app-purchases products in your app are approved? you can get these info from the dashboard---Add-ons.

> Is there a way to test real in-apps on Windows 8.1 before making app available for all?

According to the [Beta testing and targeted distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/beta-testing-and-targeted-distribution), there's no specific option for Windows 8.1 beta testing currently. But you can also download your app on Windows 10 device to test if your IAP product without problem. If it can work well, then you can make it available to all users. This seems to the only work-around.

Please also note that it will take 1-2 days after that for IAP feature from real products to start serving.

Comment: You guys make me crazy with your win/win-phone dashboard and services user experience from their beginning - you burn bridges to previous OS versions before I can implement workarounds for our customers with "old" OS. But the great news that you provide us with win developer images for vmware player and I've tested iaps somehow in win 10. Could you please point me to _actual_ documentation about In-app-purchases for win 8.1/wp 8.1 (not 10)? I need to support users with W8.1 and as I investigate your api works not the way your docs say in many small details (in emergency cases).

Comment: For example, CurrentApp.GetAppReceiptAsync() will not return product receipt in app receipt if it is consumable and was purchased before, but not fulfilled (CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(product_id) returns ProductPurchaseStatus.NotFulfilled). Docs promise it will be in app receipt while it is not fulfilled, but I tested several times on real device, and it is not true.

Comment: And almost every time I launch app on nokia lumia 920 from vs 2015 on win 8.1 or win 10, it crashes. I thought it is because I develop on Win8.1, but in YOUR OWN vm image with everything set up for development doesn't work properly and crashes. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Tertium Currently there is no specific option for Windows 8.1 beta testing, so I suggest you to download your app on Windows 10 device to test if your IAP product without problem.

Comment: @Tertium About your second question, can you provide the related document for me, so that I can help you to check it.

Comment: I've found that on WinPhone 8.1 after the purchase (real) I get app receipt without any purchase in any case. So I have to check for unfulfilled transactions to get trID. But on Win10 I get purchase receipt (as promised) and it has all the info. So I suppose your docs about in-app purchases on WP 8.1 are outdated. The most painful problem is permanent crashes of VS2015 while deploying to Nokia920 (with fully updated firmware) even on your the last and up to date win10 image.